# Hibernate 5 mapping on a foreign key

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, annotations

I am currently studying hibernate and i have the following postgresql table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_secure
(
  plug_id bigserial NOT NULL,
  plug_name text DEFAULT ''::text,
  plug_user text DEFAULT ''::text,
  CONSTRAINT "PK_PLUG_ID" PRIMARY KEY (plug_id),
  CONSTRAINT tbl_secure_plug_user_fkey FOREIGN KEY (plug_user)
      REFERENCES auth_users (username) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)

CREATE TABLE auth_users
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass),
  username character varying(64) NOT NULL,
  passwd character varying(64) NOT NULL,
  pass_expiry date DEFAULT ((now())::date + '1 mon'::interval),
  CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT auth_users_username_key UNIQUE (username)
)
```

and hibernate annotated entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_secure",schema="public")
public class TblSecure  implements java.io.Serializable {

     private Long plugId;
     private AuthUsers authUsers;
     private String plugName;

    public TblSecure() {
    }

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="plug_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    public Long getPlugId() {
        return this.plugId;
    }

    public void setPlugId(Long plugId) {
        this.plugId = plugId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="plug_user")
    public AuthUsers getAuthUsers() {
        return this.authUsers;
    }

    public void setAuthUsers(AuthUsers authUsers) {
        this.authUsers = authUsers;
    }


    @Column(name="plug_name")
    public String getPlugName() {
        return this.plugName;
    }

    public void setPlugName(String plugName) {
        this.plugName = plugName;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name="auth_users",schema="public", uniqueConstraints =@UniqueConstraint(columnNames="username"))

public class AuthUsers  implements java.io.Serializable {
     private Long id;
     private String username;
     private String passwd;
     private Set tblSecures = new HashSet(0);

    public AuthUsers() {
    }

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)

    @Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Column(name="username", unique=true, nullable=false, length=64)
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }


    @Column(name="passwd", nullable=false, length=64)
    public String getPasswd() {
        return this.passwd;
    }

    public void setPasswd(String passwd) {
        this.passwd = passwd;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="authUsers")
    public Set<TblSecure> getTblSecures() {
        return this.tblSecures;
    }

    public void setTblSecures(Set<TblSecure> tblSecures) {
        this.tblSecures = tblSecures;
    }
}
```

---

i'm trying to fetch using HQL:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from TblSecure sec WHERE        sec.uathUser.username=:pUser AND sec.plugName=:pName AND     sec.plugSystem=:pSystem");

query.setParameter("pUser", "user");

query.setParameter("pName", "plugname");

query.setParameter("pSystem", "projectname");

List<TblSecure> result = query.list();

for(TblSecure sec2 : result){
 ///
}
```

---

The error im getting is:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist:
>   text = bigint
>
> due to this hibernate formatted sql :
>   "tblsecure0_.plug_user=authusers1_.id"

it should be comparing `tblsecure0_.plug_user=authusers1_.username` instead.

Hope someone can help me if i have an incorrect association mapping.

TIA :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use `@ManyToOne` with relation to a foreign key that is not a primary key in the other table.

In that case you need to add extra information to make that work:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="plug_user", referencedColumnName="username")
public AuthUsers getAuthUsers() {
    return this.authUsers;
}
```

Comment: great. glad i could help